# Is it "Zee" or "Zed"?

Tags: pronunciation, letters-of-the-alphabet

When is "**z**" pronounced "**zee**" and when "**zed**"?

From what I found out "**zee**" is AmE and "**zed**" is BrE. And in abbreviations the letter is always pronounced "**zee**" like in **LZ** *(landing zone)*.